# how to include mail templet in asp.net using identity?

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-identity, asp.net-4.5

i am trying to include email templet when user click on reset the password the mail will send with specific templet using Identity
bellow is my code for sending mail and i want to include the mail templet

```
 protected void Forgot(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (IsValid)
            {
            // Validate the user's email address
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            ApplicationUser user = manager.FindByName(Email.Text);
            if (user == null || !manager.IsEmailConfirmed(user.Id))
                {
                FailureText.Text = "The user either does not exist or is not confirmed.";
                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                return;
                }
            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send email with the code and the redirect to reset password page
            string code = manager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id);
            string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetResetPasswordRedirectUrl(code, Request);
            manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>."); // here i want to include email templet
            loginForm.Visible = false;
            DisplayEmail.Visible = true;

            }
        }
```

i can not figured out how to do this  kindly help me on this

Comment: i am able to send & receive mail successfully but want to set specific format for the mail

Comment: what exactly you want your email looks like, give an example?

Comment: hi ronaldinho, for example when i click on reset password i am getting mail like this "Please reset the password by click <Link>, so instead of sending one link i would like to send entire email template with reset link here is the example [link](https://fast.customer.io/j/cloudapp_welcomeverification.png)

Comment: if found the solution thanks for wiving my question ;)